# Why do the calculated means in lm() differ from emmeans()?

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, lm, lsmeans

Let's assume we have the data:

```
> d <- as.data.frame(list(y = c(10.9510128075768, 9.61076281828162, 9.71566933820043, 
10.8574097780798, 11.7196272991206, 10.2700549009372, 9.57781599021236, 
8.81088670514042, 9.66896702112099, 9.06017067348998, 9.74106741688122, 
10.3943791682216, 9.14814290797614, 12.6491668810949, 10.1560116756651, 
11.1302072674549, 7.71087602015989, 10.7410011571954, 8.68375483954844, 
10.9198036776091, 13.398130155452, 12.5924714207302, 14.3242586301773, 
12.2987683307531, 12.4193856957595, 11.9989278189746, 12.3318213932466, 
13.9451849533731, 13.4337021495452, 14.005159217677, 12.6098813359463, 
13.3763702917746, 13.2441649244865, 11.5737426576175, 14.7784292874755, 
13.1344476609337, 13.7655989991579, 13.955136676909, 12.9494342985577, 
12.694184580233, 13.8936737024255, 11.9527018509387, 14.9713373862242, 
12.6163678937116, 14.654145302275, 14.5122126939506, 13.0829657335859, 
13.5672209148515, 11.9754515204655, 13.3230065030224, 14.0436124583562, 
13.0990784868972, 12.5458630908456, 12.3442181475496, 12.9640775773775, 
14.0691614606768, 12.5160250696987, 12.8789898886726, 11.7058599961792, 
13.4943128360149, 4.30790152011415, 4.49704100940278, 3.81470273089736, 
1.13021120979739, 3.48202950412376, 3.4561356033012, 2.64659971417009, 
3.17048947094798, 2.1359640458731, 3.67923077401566), x1 = c("T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", 
"T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T1", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", 
"T2", "T2", "T2", "T2", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", "T3", 
"T3", "T3", "T3"), x2 = c(0.672898985346896, -0.569082185143952, 
0.632549243829518, 2.36443492906985, 0.665718635268836, 1.7327500422091, 
1.94658564019779, 1.00439870432637, 0.647677694450151, 0.470304490866496, 
1.7395892255748, -0.0634574154828123, 1.2462108435364, 0.710500633435688, 
-1.26488935648794, -0.408850456073194, 1.91601932879257, 0.808721049464801, 
1.80328321613365, 2.8874744633086, 13.4738811811091, 12.677268492313, 
12.3799626865667, 11.8072015735427, 13.5778917949044, 12.5962341093185, 
10.8264230591286, 11.8443574651097, 10.0810901797302, 11.8047411538894, 
9.40767233005401, 13.3140021671981, 11.3644569989679, 11.5700211613058, 
11.830681667698, 12.6122181739891, 12.6783401772227, 12.5679519724717, 
11.4274573960739, 10.6367087437217, 11.6112777556621, 12.2779141324505, 
11.176918878428, 11.9311590655215, 10.8323376738702, 11.9916909857844, 
12.1288554015974, 11.854124371539, 11.8360890432639, 13.7635520027849, 
12.7625865124183, 13.1114310807306, 11.0767930471702, 12.164341838428, 
13.1548251870973, 11.9434785754735, 9.87063935176535, 12.3448457620995, 
10.0950445544145, 11.1888298468598, 4.3240043212996, 3.61563684930267, 
4.09166895553536, 3.30660486151363, 2.88984123751714, 2.07568722687272, 
4.59291375371919, 3.04501059812188, 2.28487159933212, 3.86522309971714
), ID = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L)))
```

I'm interested in values of y at X1=T1...T3 adjusted for X2.

The means taken from lm():

```
> summary(lm(y~x1+x2,data=d))

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = d)

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.39798 -0.60836  0.01702  0.73175  2.58139 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value            Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) 10.04356    0.24784  40.524 <0.0000000000000002 ***
x1T2         2.72726    1.33580   2.042              0.0452 *  
x1T3        -6.92770    0.48213 -14.369 <0.0000000000000002 ***
x2           0.03408    0.11955   0.285              0.7765    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.9859 on 66 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9265,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.9232 
F-statistic: 277.3 on 3 and 66 DF,  p-value: < 0.00000000000000022
```

are:

```
> with(as.data.frame(t(coef(lm(y~x1+x2,data=d)))), data.frame(x1T1=`(Intercept)`, x1T2=`(Intercept)`+x1T2, x1T3=`(Intercept)`+x1T3))
      x1T1     x1T2    x1T3
1 10.04356 12.77083 3.11586
```

This differs from raw means, so I assume this is corrected for X2:

```
> tapply(d$y, d$x1, mean)
       T1        T2        T3 
10.075839 13.175987  3.232031
```

So why the LS-Means are different from the lm()? Isn't lm() corrected for X2?

```
emmeans(lm(y~x1+x2,data=d), "x1")
 x1 emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 T1  10.30 0.820 66     8.66    11.94
 T2  13.03 0.542 66    11.95    14.11
 T3   3.37 0.585 66     2.20     4.54
```

So what are the means taken from lm(), if not raw means and not LS-means? I am interested in the means of y at each time point, corrected for x2

I think I found the answer: [Why are emmeans package means different than regular means?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/427004/why-are-emmeans-package-means-different-than-regular-means)

So lm() gives me the ordinary marginal means, based on data, and EM - estimated ones, based on a model. But which one are better in my case? If you are asked to report adjusted means, would you pick those form lm or emmeans? I believe SAS users choose LS-means (emmeans), while R users lm()? Or is there any good guideline?

Comment: See ["What are LS means useful for?"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/332167).

Comment: I don't think that @RichardHardy's posting has any relevance to this question; because this question involves a single factor and a covariate, and Hardy's posting expresses concerns about the way that EMMs average over factor levels when there are two or more factors involved.

Comment: @rvl, thanks; I did not intend it as a duplicate but as a side reference.

Comment: RE: *"Isn't lm() corrected for X2?"* It is not corrected for `X2`, but you set `X2` to zero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EMMs are a linear function of the regression coefficients. You can always tell what that linear function is by looking at the `linfct` slot of the object that `emmeans()` creates:

```
> mod = lm(formula = y ~ x1 + x2, data = d)
> (emm = emmeans(mod, "x1"))
 x1 emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 T1  10.30 0.820 66     8.66    11.94
 T2  13.03 0.542 66    11.95    14.11
 T3   3.37 0.585 66     2.20     4.54

Confidence level used: 0.95 
> emm@linfct
     (Intercept) x1T2 x1T3       x2
[1,]           1    0    0 7.551851
[2,]           1    1    0 7.551851
[3,]           1    0    1 7.551851
```

Note that the value for `x2` is just its overall mean:

```
> mean(d$x2)
[1] 7.551851
```

In fact, in this example, the EMMs are just predictions for the three `x1` levels at the mean of `x2`:

```
> predict(mod, newdata = data.frame(x1 = c("T1", "T2", "T3"), x2 = 7.551851))
        1         2         3 
10.300902 13.028164  3.373198
```

These are also known as the "adjusted means" in the context of analysis of covariance.